# React drag and drop kit

Tags: reactjs, dnd-kit

Drag is working but drop is not.
I am trying to build a web app kind of image gallery, getting data from pexels api.
one of it's feature should allow the user to drag and drop images hence changing it's original order but when i try to drag and drop, it goes to it's original place. I dont understand what am i doing wrong... here is my code ->

Home.jsx

```
import Navbar from "../Navbar";
import PhotoGallery from "../PhotoGallery";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { fetchPexelsImages } from "../PexelsService";
const Home = () => {
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPhotos = async () => {
      try {
        const fetchedPhotos = await fetchPexelsImages();
        setPhotos(fetchedPhotos);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle error
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    getPhotos();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <PhotoGallery photos={photos} setPhotos={setPhotos} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

PhotoGallery.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { fetchPexelsImages } from "./PexelsService";
import { DndContext, closestCenter } from "@dnd-kit/core";
import {
  arrayMove,
  SortableContext,
  rectSwappingStrategy,
} from "@dnd-kit/sortable";
import SortablePhoto from "./SortablePhoto";

function PhotoGallery({ photos, setPhotos }) {
  const handleDragEnd = (event) => {
    const { active, over } = event;

    if (active.id === over.id) {
      return;
    }
    setPhotos((items) => {
      const activeIndex = items.indexOf(active.id);
      const overIndex = items.indexOf(over.id);
      return arrayMove(items, activeIndex, overIndex);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto my-4">
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Photo Gallery</h1>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
        <DndContext
          collisionDetection={closestCenter}
          onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
        >
          <SortableContext items={photos} strategy={rectSwappingStrategy}>
            {photos.map((photo) => (
              <SortablePhoto key={photo.id} photo={photo} />
            ))}
          </SortableContext>
        </DndContext>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PhotoGallery;
```

SortablePhoto.jsx

```
import { useSortable } from "@dnd-kit/sortable";
import { CSS } from "@dnd-kit/utilities";

const SortablePhoto = ({ photo }) => {
  const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform, transition } =
    useSortable({ id: photo.id });

  const style = { transition, transform: CSS.Transform.toString(transform) };

  return (
    <div ref={setNodeRef} style={style} {...attributes} {...listeners}>
      <div className="bg-gray-200 p-4 rounded-lg shadow-md">
        <img
          src={photo.src.medium}
          alt={photo.alt}
          className="w-full h-auto rounded-md"
        />
        <p className="text-center mt-2 text-gray-700">{photo.photographer}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SortablePhoto;
```

I have tried DnD kit and i expect it to work

Comment: Use `findIndex` instead of `indexOf`. indexOf will not work because items contains array of objects. You need use findIndex to find the index like this: `const activeIndex = items.findIndex((item) => item.id === active.id);`. Same for overIndex. Hope this solve your problem